# The process of NameNode isn't present when executing jps

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to the Hadoop ecosystem,

I installed hadooop 3.3.0 as a Pseudo-Distributed Mode.
The all application http://localhost:8088/ is working but to view name node of the application on http://localhost:9870/ i couldn't (This site can’t be reached).

```
$ jps
24553 Jps
20537 NodeManager
20429 ResourceManager
```

and

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 3.3.0
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r aa96f1871bfd858f9bac59cf2a81ec470da649af
Compiled by brahma on 2020-07-06T18:21Z
Compiled with protoc 3.7.1
From source with checksum 5dc29b802d6ccd77b262ef9d04d19c4
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.3.0.jar
```

I tried to restart the process but in vain

```
$ stop-all.sh
WARNING: Stopping all Apache Hadoop daemons as mhannani in 10 seconds.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Stopping namenodes on [HP]
Stopping datanodes
Stopping secondary namenodes [HP]
2021-01-06 16:42:07,540 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Stopping nodemanagers

Stopping resourcemanager
```

format :

```
$ hdfs  namenode -format
2021-01-06 16:44:14,683 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = HP/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 3.3.0
```

and then

```
$ start-all.sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as mhannani in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [HP]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [HP]
HP: ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 29847
2021-01-06 16:45:38,266 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
```

Please how can i fix that, in order to access my hdfs file system from the browser as it was on earlier version of Hadoop on http://localhost:9870/50075 ?

Any help or advice would be appreciated, Thanks folks.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should remove 127.0.1.1 from /etc/hosts... But you need to show the logs of the namenode process

Comment: Thanks for the response, The issue was just the path to the `nameNode` and the `dataNode` on `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not setting correctly the namenode path, and datanode paths of my local file systems :

on `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml` :

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </property>
    
   <property>
      <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>file://AbsolutePATH/TO/WHERE/THE/namenode/Should/be/stored</value>
   </property>
    
   <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
      <value>file://The/same/for/dataNode</value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```